# returning data from db up to controller

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, asynchronous

I am building a new API in Express using an MVC architecture and I cannot get the data to return to the controllers file from the db access file.

I started this out trying to use callback functions and then switched to promises, but i'm pretty sure I am missing something about the scopes that is causing my problem. I have racked my brain as well as Google over and over and worked on this for a couple days to no avail.

//This is the controllers file code

```
let bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const dbUtilities = require('../db/db.js');

let controller = {
  retrieveTables: function(req, res){
    database = req.params.database;
    query = ["SHOW TABLES FROM " +database +";"];
    connectDb(query, database, function(results){
      res.render('dashboard', {data: results});
      console.log('results from controller' + results);
    });
  },
```

//This is my db.js file that handles data retrieval from mysql

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

//generalized utility db functions
//function to open a db connection

//opening the connection to the database
connectDb = function(query, database){  
resultData = [];
  var connectionPromise = dbConnect(database);
    connectionPromise.then(function(connection){
      for(var i = 0; i < query.length; i++){
        var queryPromise = buildQuery(connection, query[i]);
        queryPromise.then(function(result){
          console.log('QUERY' + i + ': ' + query[i]);
          console.log(result);
          resultData.push(result);
          if(resultData.length == query.length){
            dbDisconnect(connection);
            return(resultData);
          }
        })
      }
    });

//opening the db connection
function dbConnect(database){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host : 'localhost',
      user : 'rcg',
      password: '8693ViaMallorca',
      database: database
    });

    connection.connect(function(err) {
      if(err) {
        console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
        reject(error);
      }
      else{
        console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadID);
        resolve(connection);
      }
    });
  });
}

//building the query promise function
function buildQuery(connection, query){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    connection.query(query, function(error, results, fields){
      if(error){
        console.error('error retrieving the query');
        console.log(query);
        reject(error);
      }
      else{
        resolve(results);
      };
    });
  });
}

//closing the connection to the database
function dbDisconnect(connection){
  connection.end(function(err) {
    if(err) {
      console.error('error terminating connection');
      return(error);
    }
    else{
      return(console.log('connection successfully terminated'));
    }
  });
}

}
module.exports = connectDb;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you edit your question to add a specific error message? Or an idea what might not be failing from console output?

Comment: I'd also recommend taking a look at a library like [Knex](https://knexjs.org/) instead of rolling your own.

Comment: The res.render call from the controller file is always undefined. The data never seems to make it back to the controllers file.

Comment: I think the issue does not lie with the SQL as I can send the results from the db.js file and they show up properly. Its an issue of getting the data to return to the original calling function.

Comment: what is the value of `results` in the `queryPromise` block?

Comment: It gives a set of objects that correspond to the set of tables that are in the database. I can console.log the data and see its correct, but if I try to console log the data from the controllers file I get nothing.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am still pretty new to async programming and its not intuitive for me yet.

Comment: I did give arrow up, but I don't have enough reputation for it to count yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this wasn't working was because you were returning only in the inner callback. You needed to return in outer callback too. The data had no return path to get back to the callee (eg: the controller). Since you mentioned async/await, I re-wrote this to reflect modern async/await syntax.

```
const connectDb = async function(query, database){  
  resultArray = [];
  const connection = await dbConnect(database);

  for(let i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {
    const result = await buildQuery(connection, query[i]);
    console.log(result);
    resultArray.push(result);
  }
  return resultArray;
});
```

I re-wrote this to use the same async/await syntax as below. You could use the callback syntax you're currently using, but you wouldn't be able to use the code below without changing it. I think the async/await syntax is more straightforward. It's also important that you have `res.render` as the last thing in your function (since it's signifying as a callback that you're done processing the request).

```
const controller = {
  retrieveTables: async function(req, res) {
    const database = req.params.database;
    const query = ["SHOW TABLES FROM " + database + ";"];

    const results = await connectDb(query, database);
    console.log('results from controller', results);
    res.render('dashboard', {data: results});
  }
}
```